# Add read more /read less button on WooCommerce archive product category description

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, wordpress, woocommerce

I am using JS to create a read more button/read less button on the WooCommerce archive product category description. To hide some of the text into a read-more expandable div

The read more button is working & the read less button is working, but it stops working after both read more and read less button events/functions have been clicked once each:

```js
jQuery( function( $ ) {
    $(document).ready(function() {
        //Get the current height of the description container
        let curHeight = $(".archive-description").height();

        //Set the height of the description container
        $(".archive-description").css({
            "height": "80px", 
            "overflow": "none",
        });

        //Add 'Read more button
        $(".archive-description").after( "<button class='read-more'>Read more...</button>" );

        //Set description container back to its original height
        $( ".read-more" ).on( "click", function() {
            $(".archive-description").animate({height: curHeight});
            $('.read-more').hide();
            $(".archive-description").after( "<button class='read-less'>Read less...</button>" );
        });
    });
    
    $(document).on('click', '.read-less', function () {
        $(".archive-description").animate({height: 80});
        $('.read-less').hide();
        $(".archive-description").after( "<button class='read-more'>Read more...</button>" );
    });
});
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Once read more or read less are clicked, they are getting re-generated by the jQuery code dynamically.

So now they are not the part of initial rendered DOM. To Address them, you need to use the `.on` handler.

So convert like this:

```
$(document).on( "click",".read-more", function() {
    $(".archive-description").animate({height: curHeight});
    $('.read-more').hide();
    $(".archive-description").after( "<button class='read-less'>Read less...</button>" );
});
```

Comment: Thank you - perfect. Working correctly now.

Answer (score 0):

The reason why you can only target them once is because they are being added after the `DOM` is in `ready` state.

You could instead call them like:

```
$(document).on("click", ".read-more", function () {
    $(".archive-description").animate({height: curHeight});
    $('.read-more').hide();
    $(".archive-description").after("<button class='read-less'>Read less...</button>");
});
```

Answer (score 0):

I've used event delegation to handle the click events for both "Read more" and "Read less" buttons, ensuring that they work correctly for dynamically added buttons. Additionally, I changed the CSS overflow property to "hidden" for the description container to hide the overflowed text when it's collapsed

```
jQuery(function ($) {
    $(document).ready(function () {
        // Get the current height of the description container
        let curHeight = $(".archive-description").height();

        // Set the height of the description container
        $(".archive-description").css({
            "height": "80px",
            "overflow": "hidden", // Change "none" to "hidden" for correct behavior
        });

        // Add 'Read more' button
        $(".archive-description").after("<button class='read-more'>Read more...</button>");

        // Handle 'Read more' button click
        $(document).on("click", ".read-more", function () {
            $(".archive-description").animate({ height: curHeight });
            $(this).hide();
            $(".archive-description").after("<button class='read-less'>Read less...</button>");
        });

        // Handle 'Read less' button click using event delegation
        $(document).on("click", ".read-less", function () {
            $(".archive-description").animate({ height: "80px" });
            $(this).hide();
            $(".archive-description").next(".read-more").show();
        });
    });
});
```